# Do I need to normalize an image before smoothing it with a Gaussian Filter

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I have a real image with range [0 255]. I want to apply Gaussian filter to smooth it. As I know, the Guided filter needs the image to be normalized before being applied. However, I am not sure what is the case for the Gaussian filter. The code example in MATLAB 2015b does not normalize the image before applying the Gaussian filter. My question is: **Do I need to normalize the image before smoothing it with Gaussian Filter?** Thanks.

```
%% This code did not normalize image
I = imread('cameraman.tif');
Iblur = imgaussfilt(I, 2);
```

Answer (score 5):

Gaussian filter is just a weighted average filter. There is no need for normalization.